# No such thing as electrostatic force

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

Is it true that there is no such thing as an electrostatic force because all charges are moving relative to each other (there is no absolute rest in our universe) so experience an electric force?

Would an expert please let me know if I am conceptually wrong and why.

Comment: There is no absolute rest, but objects can be at rest with respect to each other.  I'd like to know what the genesis of your question is.   What did you read that prompted the question?

Answer (score 7):

Within reasonable approximation in a chosen reference frame, there are electrostatic forces. For example, in some laboratory, someone could pin down two charges to the table and they would experience an electrostatic force among them. Alternatively, one could have a really large, static concentration of charge and bring in a small, test charge around it. The electric force felt by the test charge would quite often be called an electrostatic force, since it is due to a static field (within a reasonable approximation).

It should be remarked, however, that what is a electrostatic force in the lab frame is less simple in other frames of reference. Due to relativistic effects, frames of reference moving relative to the lab will perceive the same force as being due to a combination of electric and magnetic effects, neither of which will be static, since the source charge that is static in the lab frame is moving in the new frame.